# Calling an ASCX gives me a 404 in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ascx

I am trying to load an ascx file using ajax inside a page using jQuery.

It seems to however return a 404.7 and the url exists and is correct.

I get the same issue on IIS and when executing the project in VS locally.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Even if I try to enter the correct url in a web browser I get the same error.

Thanks

Comment: Not able to get your question correctly..Can you put your code snippet here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to HTTP 404.7 error message: "**request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension**"

Probably you have to allow ascx extension in your web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
       <add fileExtension=".ascx" allowed="true" />
```

...